A covering property for the discrete subgroups of a topological group
There is an example in the book "Fundamentals
of Algebraic
Topology" by Steven H. Weintraub saying that when G is a topological group and  H is any discrete subgroup of G,
then the projection p : G → H\G (the space of left cosets, with the quotient
topology) is a covering projection (Example 2.2.3.). I can prove it only when $H$ is also normal---The point is to find an open neighborhood $U$ of $1$, whose images under the left multiplications of the elements of  $H$ are all disjoint (This existence of $U$ does not require $H$ to be normal, and a proof can be found in
$H$ a discrete subgroup of topological group $G$ $\implies$ there exists an open $U\supseteq\{1\}$ s.t. the $hU$ are pairwise disjoint . ), then I can prove the existence of the covering neighborhoods of $p(H)$. However, when I try to 'copy' these neighborhoods to cover an arbitrary left coset $gH$, I have to assume that $H$ is normal, which makes me doubt the  original statement in the text. Is it correct?

Why do you use disjointness under right multiplication instead of left multiplication?

The original statement is definitely correct.

The point is that multiplication still slides the open nbhds around the right way to get a covering, even though $G/H$ need not be a group.  It still has this decent left action.

Only right multiplications can ensure the injectivity of $p|_{U}$, which is also the reason why I need $H$ to be normal after  sliding these nbhds.@Randall

The statement "Only right multiplications can ensure the injectivity of $p|_U$" is quite false. If you want somebody to find a mistake in your reasoning, you would edit your question by providing details of your attempted proof.

To prove the injectivity of $p|_U$, suppose  we have two points $g_1,g_2\in U$ with $p(g_1)=p(g_2)$, i.e. $g_1g^{-1}_2\in H$ (For we are dealing with left cosets.),by the notation in  link, we have $g_1g^{-1}_2\in V$ , and therefore must be $1$.

In the link, the answer used the function $G\times G\rightarrow G, (x,y)\mapsto xy^{-1}$, which can only lead to disjointness of sets like $h_1U,h_2U,\cdots$.

I really do not understand why do you think there is any need to consider the action of $H$ by right multiplication:
Since $H< G$ is discrete, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $1\in G$ such that $H\cap U=\{1\}$. Since $G$ is a topological group, there is another neighborhood $W$ of $1\in G$ such that
$$
W W^{-1}\subset U. 
$$
Now, suppose that $h\in H$ is such that $hW\cap W\ne \emptyset$. Thus, there are $w_1, w_2\in W$ such that
$$
hw_1=w_2.
$$
Hence, $h=w_2 w_1^{-1}\in W W^{-1}\subset U$. Since $h\in H$, it follows that $h=1$.
To verify that the left action of $H$ on $G$ is a covering action, take a general point $g\in G$ and consider its neighborhood $Wg$ where $W$ is as above. Then for every $h\in H$ we have
$$
h(Wg)\cap Wg=(hW \cap W)g 
$$
which is empty unless $h=1$. Thus, the action of $H$ on $G$ is a covering group action and, therefore, the projection
$$
G\to H\backslash G
$$
is a covering map.

Apologies, I realized that I had been mistakenly interpreting 'right action' as 'left action' in my mind, which led to the earlier confusion. I've now edited the original question. However,  when I 'glide' this collection of disjoint open sets to another coset, the normality of $H $ is still required in order to prove that $ p $ remains injective on the translated open sets, .

@LDLSS: I have no idea what you mean by "gliding." I suggest you review the notion of quotient under a group action.

@LDLSS: I see what your problem is, you are still confusing left and right cosets, even after the edit of your question. ("However, when I try to 'copy' these neighborhoods to cover an arbitrary left coset ") I suggest you also review the notion of a covering group action, it will be explained in any algebraic topology textbook.

Now I realize that the issue arose from confusing the condition for the left coset with that for the right coset，the correct condition should be $ x \sim y \iff x^{-1}y \in H $, Thus, the neighborhood $ W $ should be chosen such that $W^{-1}W \in U $. We can then analyze the form of $ g(Wh) $ for $ h \in H $ and $ g \in G $. Since I have not yet studied covering group actions, I have to prove this by definition. Thank you for your patience and thoughtful participation in the discussion.

What I understand by covering group action is that it's a covering where group action should map different sheets above each point of base space to other sheets in a way that reflects the local homeomorphism between $\pi^{-1}(U)$ and $U$. So here the cosets are our disjoint sheets, right? @MoisheKohan And why we showed $h(Wg)\cap Wg = (hW\cap W)g$ unless $h=1$ in the last paragraph? Does it mean we translate our $W$ and check the group action reflects the local homeomorphism and disjointness?

@Dr.Antidode: This verifies the definition of a covering group action. This definition is designed to guarantee that the quotient map $G\to H\backslash G$ is a covering map.
